# No me deja Iniciar Sesión en HEROKU

Tags: nodejs, hosting, heroku, deployment, timeout

estoy intentando hacer Deploy en mi app de node js.
El problema es que a la hora de hacer **heroku login** me sale este error

```
PS C:\Users\usuario\Documents\APPS\proyecto node> heroku login 
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: C:\Program 
Files\heroku\client\node_modules\cli-ux\node_modules\@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:42
    throw err;
    ^ 
CLIError: timed out
at Object.error (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\cli-ux\node_modules\@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:26:15)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\@heroku-cli\command\lib\login.js:27:38)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) { 
oclif: { exit: 2 }, 
code: undefined
}
```

si alguien le paso este problema y puede ayudarme se lo agradecería

Comment: Te pide que presiones cualquier tecla para abrir un navegador o `q` para salir. Por lo visto no estás presionando nada y sale por `timeout`.

Comment: muchas gracias, que tonto fui jajajaj

Comment: heroku login -i
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Deberia dejarte .
.
.
.
.
.
.
.